# Django: Autosave different default dates for different occurrences of the same form?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

Building a Django app where for each day of the week, weight and calorie data needs to be inputted and saved to the respective date.

I currently have it designed so that the template renders Mon, Tues, Wed, etc. with a form for each day connected to the same mode via a modelform. My problem is that with `auto_now`, `auto_now_add` and `default=today.date()` the date is fixed. I.e - if Monday is the 1st of the month, I'd like it so that when a user inputs his Tuesday weight and calories, it autosaves to the 2nd of the month. Here is my code:

Template:

```
     <form method='POST'> {% csrf_token %}
     {{ mainform.as_p }}
     <input type="submit" value="save" />
     </form>
     Tuesday
     <form method='POST'> {% csrf_token %}
     {{ mainform.as_p }}
     <input type="submit" value="save" />
```

Form:

```
    class Meta:
        model = Daily_Inputs
        fields = [
            "Daily_Weight",
            "Daily_Cals",
            "Daily_Date",
        ]
```

View:

```
    initinputz = Initial_Inputs.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    mainform = Daily_Inputs_Form()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        mainform = Daily_Inputs_Form(request.POST)
        if mainform.is_valid():
            maininstance = mainform.save(commit=False)
            maininstance.user = request.user
            maininstance.save()
 
    context = {
        'initz': initinputz,
        'mainform': mainform,
    }

    return render(request, "pages/home.html", context)
```

Model:

```
    Daily_Weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2, verbose_name=None, null=True)
    Daily_Cals = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=None, null=True)
    Daily_Date = models.DateField(default=date.today())
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=None, null=True)
```

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into having a hidden field. So you would remove the auto date from the model.

Then manully add a input field that is hidden and where you have assigned the date to value.

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{week_date}}">
```

Then you would need some python code to get all dates for the current week.